# How to include gap in between table borders?

Tags: html, css

I created a webpage where I need to display three tables side by side. But I can't figure out how to include gap/space in between table borders? Right now, it's touching each other's borders.

I have tried the following code.
https://jsfiddle.net/14ayr783/

```css
table,th,td {
  border:5px solid crimson;
}

table {
  float:left;
  width:33%;
  border-collapse:collapse;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly - you should remove `border-collapse: collapse` as it merges neighbouring borders into single border. Also add `<table cellspacing="5">`

Comment: Even if I remove border-collapse, the borders are still touching. Do I need to put table cellspacing in each of the table or what?

Answer (score 0):

If you want space between tables use `margin-right: 10px;` on tables.

If you want space between cells inside tables then use what **maciejze** suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `Flexbox` container and remove the `float` from the tables

```
.container {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: space-between;
}

table {
    flex-basis: 33%;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
```

JsFiddle fork: https://jsfiddle.net/yx5eL6bf/

Answer (score -1):

try adding this css

```css
table {
  float:left;
  width:32%;
  border-collapse:collapse;
  margin:3px;
}
```